# How do you simplify $\cup\{A, \cup A\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I want to simplify $\cup\{A, \cup A\},$ and also $\cup\cup\{A, \cup A\},$ so forth. I thought $\cup\{A, \cup A\}$ would not be simplified more. To say this in plain english, this union is a set that contains 1) all elements in $A$ and 2) all elements in all elements in $A,$ which I am not sure how to simplify. Then $\cup\cup\{A, \cup A\}$ is a set that contains all elements in the first union that I just described. Is it possible to simplify this union more? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see what I posted was included in your post. Yes, I think it is correct and that It cannot be simplified any further.

Comment: No worries! Thank you very much :) Do you think it'd be possible to simplify the second set? I thought not, but I wanted some more insights.

Comment: What kind of notation is this? Is $\cup\{A,\cup A\}$ simply the set $A\cup\bigcup_{x\in A} x$?

Comment: Look at my edits to see how to use MathJax properly.

Comment: $$\text{Suppose } A = \big\{ \{1,2\},\{2,3\}\big\}.$$
$$\text{Then } \cup A= \{1,2,3\}.$$
$$\text{And } \{ A,\cup A \} = \Big\{ \big\{\{1,2\},\{2,3\}\big\}, \{1,2,3\} \Big\}.$$
$$
\begin{align}
\text{So } & {\cup\{A,\cup A\}} \\ {} \\
= {} & \big\{\{1,2\},\{2,3\}\big\} \cup \{1,2,3\} \\ {} \\
= {} & \big\{ \{1,2\},\{2,3\}, 1,2,3
 \big\}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @EvangelosBampas : This notation is used when set theory is not merely used in some other areas of mathematics, but rather is done for the purpose of understanding set theory.
$$
\underbrace{\quad \cup A \quad}_\text{set theorists' notation} = \underbrace{ \quad \bigcup_{x\in A} x \quad }_\text{common mathematicians' notation}
$$

Comment: Yes, @EvangelosBampas, that's the set I'm talking about and the notation is from enderton set theory.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHardy for fixing MathJax. I'm new to this platform and also new to LaTex in general!

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, my question was regarding the final step in one of the exercises in my set theory textbook, where I had to simplify some set notation

Comment: @MichaelHardy OK, thanks.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Except for the fact that one should still write $\bigcup A$ and not $\cup A$.

Answer (score 0):

You might or might not consider it a simplification, but, of course, $\bigcup \left\{A, \bigcup A\right\} = A \cup \bigcup A.$